# CSS not aligning properly, overlapping another box

Tags: css, drupal, drupal-7

Having a bit of an issue with a Drupal site. If you take a look here and look down at the facebook block, it's overlapping the blocks above it, the twitter one is not doing this. I have tried various changes in Drupal but nothing has changed. Anyone have any idea how to make it line up with the twitter one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the two margin top properties asigned to the .block-facebook-wall. Disable those.

```
    .block-facebook-wall {
        /* margin-top: -7.36714em; */
    }

    media (min-width: 38em){
    .block-facebook-wall {
        width: 48.93617%;
        clear: right;
        float: right;
        margin-right: 0;
        /* margin-top: -6.8541em; */
    }
}
```